# What's the difference of using #!/usr/bin/env or #!/bin/env in shebang?

Tags: bash, env

Will there be any difference or it's just a personal choice?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`#!<interpreter> <arguments>` tries to run `<interpreter> <arguments>` to read and run the rest of the file.

So `#!/usr/bin/env` means that there must be a program called `/usr/bin/env`;
`#!/bin/env` means that there must be a program called `/bin/env`.

Some systems have one and not the other.

In my experience, most have `/usr/bin/env`, so `#!/usr/bin/env` is more common.

Unix systems will try to run `<interpreter>` using `execve`, which is why it must be a full path, and `#!env` without a path will not work.

Comment: Adding to that, non-OSX BSDs don't have `/bin/bash` so `/usr/bin/env` is recommended for portability there. Also, if you want to run a newer version of BASH in a different directory lined up in `$PATH`, `env` would respect and use that, whereas `/bin/bash` obviously hardcodes that.

Comment: Specially, OS/X has `/usr/bin/env` and does not have a symbolic link from `/bin/env` to `/usr/bin/env`.  You would get a `-bash: ./your_commnd: /bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory` error.

Answer (score 7):

#### Historically, UNIX had 2 bunches of binaries:

- `/` filesystem mounted early on boot.
- `/usr` *might* have been mounted later, possibly running scripts and programs from `/` to arrange the mount.  Example: some sites saved space by mounting /usr from network, but you need to get on the network first.  Example: it's a large local filesystem, but if it gets damaged, you want tools like `fsck` to try fixing it.

Thus, `/bin` and `/sbin` (using `/lib`), had to contain a minimal system including at least a shell at /bin/sh, scripting essentials like `/bin/echo`, `/bin/test` etc., system tools like `/bin/mount` or `/sbin/mount`, and `/sbin/fsck`...

Thus in different unixes, almost any program might have been:

- in /usr/bin/ but NOT /bin
- in /bin but NOT /usr/bin
- in both, same as symlink
- in both but different!  E.g. some systems played with `/bin/sh` being a very minimal shell (e.g. `dash`) for faster startup, but symlinking `/usr/bin/sh` -> `/usr/bin/bash` (iirc, invoking bash as "sh" puts it into some posix mode, but it's still a different more powerful shell).

Most of the time, one just sets $PATH to include both areas.  But some contexts like `#!` or `docker exec` require a fixed full path.  Thus the trick of using `env` to write portable scripts — `env` just happens to do a PATH lookup.

#### What changed

These were valid use cases but modern Linux followed a similar argument of "need small userspace to mount / recover main userspace" for `/` itself too!  [The pivot syscall and `initrd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk) were introduced, and tooling grew to copy the parts you need into it.

#### /usr unification

Now, `/` vs `/usr` arguably lost its purpose.  Having both on one filesystem and symlinking was doable for everybody *in principle*, though some particular setups would break and would have to change...

See https://lwn.net/Articles/483921/ from 2012 for overview of this "/usr unification" idea.  For example Fedora completed it: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove.  Many other distros haven't, or are still debating it, or ironing out some kinds to break less users. For example see debian's preparation: https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge.

#### /usr/local/, ~/.local/ and other places

There are more reasons to want PATH lookup:

- Not all unixes install all languages out of the box, or what they package is too old.  So while stuff like `env` always exists in /bin or /usr/bin or both, one might only have (or prefer) python and other interpreters in /usr/local, or under your home dir...
- Many language version / library managers have a way to run with an isolated environment, and frequently such environments are activated via executable "shims".  For example, a Python "virtualenv" directory has a bin/python3 binary; so when you prepend that bin/ directory to your PATH, and if you run scripts that do `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, that's all you need to use modules specific to that enviroment.

#### Back to the question, what full path to use for `env` itself?

By same logic, in systems with a distinct /usr, `env` itself might be missing from either place so you can't write a 100.00% portable `#!` line.
In practice both are likely to work.  I don't have stats, but in practice for many years I've seen `/usr/bin/env` as the more commonly recommended form ([example](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/appendix.html#executable-python-scripts))

Answer (score 2):

Mikel explanation is great, it misses just a small fact (which is rather important), it's only one argument being passed including all spaces:

```
#!<Interpreter> <argument>
```

Results in calling:

```
$ <Interpreter> '<argument>' path_to_calling_script
```

So for Example:

```
$ cat /tmp/test
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "hi"

$ /tmp/test
```

is the same as calling:

```
$ /usr/bin/env "python" /tmp/test
```

The quotes try to show that if you add any flag or other values will be part of the argument being called.

```
 #!/bin/bash -c /bin/env python
```

Will be interpreted as:

```
 $ /bin/bash "-c /bin/env python"
```

Which won't work.

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/env` is a soft link to `/bin/env`. Essentially, you are using `/bin/env`

Comment: which system has both as hard files?

Comment: Ubuntu does not have /bin/env.  Solaris 8 has both files separately.

Comment: @kurumi - most systems do not have /bin/env at all. /usr/bin/env in the standard location.

Comment: Centos 4 has `/bin/env` and `/usr/bin/env` is a symlink

Comment: Fedora completed https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/UsrMove, so nowdays /bin is symlink -> /usr/bin; RHEL/CentOS followed suit.  Many other distros haven't, or are still debating it.  See https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge, https://lwn.net/Articles/483921/.

Comment: https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/#env also mentions reverse situation: "On the other hand, there's only /bin/env at least on SCO OpenServer 5.0.6 and Cray Unicos 9.0.2 (although the latter is only of historical interest). "  That page has _extensive_ research on all aspects of `#!` portability.